# java regular Expression, fetching time out of a string

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex in java..

i have a string "2:05pm - 2:40 pm"
i need to get "2:05pm" and "2:40 pm" out from the single string using regex

I am using the follow regex expression, but I am getting wrong somewhere, don't know where

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)[:](\\d+)(\\s*)((am?)|(pm?))");
    String s = "2:05pm - 2:40pm";
    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(s);
    int i=1;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i++));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `group` is wrong: you must always use `group(0)`, which refers to the entire current match.

Overall, your regex is much too complicated, this is enough:

```
"\\d+:\\d+\\s*(a|p)m?"
```

which works in case you want input such as `1:10 a` and `1:10p` accepted, but not `1:10`. Otherwise you should use this:

```
"\\d+:\\d+\\s*(am|pm)?"
```

which will accept `1:10`, `1:10 am`, but not `1:10 a`.

If you want to validate a maximum of two digits, then use `\\d{1,2}` where you now use `\\d+`.

Comment: This is only true if you assume valid input (and that the posted in the only acceptable format, which seems like a decent assumption).  This accepts `23325:24`.

Comment: I am carrying over OP's own assumptions since I don't want to entertain too much guesswork.

Comment: What if i want to just accept max of two digits before and after :

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I added that to the answer.